# Writing directory: permission denied even though dir seems to be chmodded correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

I am having some trouble creating files in directory on my Ubuntu machine:

I added myself to the `www-data` group in order for me to easily edit stuff in my /var/www dir on my development machine.

`stat /var/www` shows the following:

```
  File: ‘/var/www’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   map
Device: 808h/2056d  Inode: 142853      Links: 3
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (   33/www-data)   Gid: (   33/www-data)
Access: 2010-12-30 16:03:18.563998000 +0100
Modify: 2010-12-30 16:02:52.663998000 +0100
Change: 2010-12-30 16:03:13.111998001 +0100
```

Still, it is impossible for me to create anything below /var/www (the only way for it to work is to `chmod` it to `777`. What am I missing?

Comment: post group file? or at least the relevant lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging out?  Or opening a new terminal window so that it picks up your new group information?

Comment: it might also work without logging out using the command: $id username

Comment: Logging out and logging in solved the problem. Argh! :)